# Has my website got a virus?

Tags: wordpress, security, malware, virus, trojan

Building a website for a customer and as I sent him a link on Skype to the new page, he said he got alerted of a trojan virus. He clicked on the link on Skype and it opened in IE, he sent me a screenshot of the message.

[image: client's screenshot of message shown when clicking the page]

I obviously ran a couple anti virus (wordpress plugins) and they came clear.

Any idea what could be causing it?

Not sure what to tell them.

Comment: I removed the link to your page as we're not going to encourage people to visit an infected website.

Comment: And it looks like you have been exploited.

Comment: I understand your concern but I have a very good version of antivirus on my computer and have been trying to replicate this problem all day with no joy. Plus the antivirus plugins I ran also said there was no malicious file so I wonder if you saw any message  yourself?

Comment: An anti-virus and WP plugin is nowhere near enough! If you are running WP, it is highly likely that your site was compromised somehow. Nearly all compromised systems we see here run WP. WP is the most hacked software ever - period. Nothing has ever come close. Sorry. Work your way through the process of cleaning up your system and making it secure. Cheers!!

Comment: These may help some: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25189/users-often-say-my-website-is-infected-but-cant-find-any-evidence-of-this/25195#25195 http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/83498/wordpress-site-hacked-phising-scam/83499#83499 There was an excellent one I was looking for that I cannot find. I will poke around some more. But this is a start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are few steps that you need to do to remove the virus:

1. Download page to your computer and set it up on your local server
2. Scan the directory with your antivirus software and delete everything that is infected
3. Update your wordpress and your themes / plugins
4. Change administrator password

//but it seems that your contact form is infected. So you can maybe localize the problem and rebuild your contact form.

After all this steps, upload everything in your public_html directory and also upload your fresh and clean database up.

This steps shall do the trick.

Comment: it helped me gain some confidence but it didn't actually solve it as antivirus software still didn't find anything, just in case it could help someone,  I kept installing different plugins until I came across this one https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/antivirus/ that finally found the attacker and I removed it. thanks for your help